# The following packages have unmet dependencies (cyclical error)

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, steam

I tried installing steam but the installation broke the package installer.

lsb_release -a :

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

This is what I tried:

sudo apt upgrade :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 i965-va-driver:i386 : Depends: libva-driver-abi-1.10:i386
 libva-glx2:i386 : Depends: libva-x11-2:i386 (>= 1.0.3) but it is not installed
                   Depends: libva2:i386 (>= 2.15.0.2) but it is not installed
                   Depends: libva2:i386 (< 2.15.0.2.1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

sudo apt install i965-va-driver :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
i965-va-driver is already the newest version (2.4.1+dfsg1-1).
i965-va-driver set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 i965-va-driver:i386 : Depends: libva-driver-abi-1.10:i386
 libva-glx2:i386 : Depends: libva-x11-2:i386 (>= 1.0.3) but it is not going to be     installed
                   Depends: libva2:i386 (>= 2.15.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libva2:i386 (< 2.15.0.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

sudo apt install -f :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libgl1-amber-dri
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libva-x11-2:i386 libva2:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libva-x11-2:i386 libva2:i386
0 to upgrade, 2 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
107 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/99.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 311 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 173053 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libva2_2.15.0.2-36_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libva2:i386 (2.15.0.2-36) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libva2_2.15.0.2-36_i386.deb (-    -unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libva2/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libva2:i386
Preparing to unpack .../libva-x11-2_2.15.0.2-36_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libva-x11-2:i386 (2.15.0.2-36) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libva-x11-2_2.15.0.236_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libva-x11-2/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other
 instances of package libva-x11-2:i386
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libva2_2.15.0.2-36_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libva-x11-2_2.15.0.2-36_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Attempts to uninstall steam fail.

Thank you

---

apt-cache policy libva-x11-2:i386 libva2:i386 libva-x11-2 libva2 :

```
libva-x11-2:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.15.0.2-36
  Version table:
     2.15.0.2-36 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu jammy/arc i386 Packages
     2.14.0-1 500
        500 http://mt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe i386 Packages
libva2:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.15.0.2-36
  Version table:
     2.15.0.2-36 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu     jammy/arc i386 Packages
     2.14.0-1 500
        500 http://mt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe i386 Packages
libva-x11-2:
  Installed: 2.15.0.2-36
  Candidate: 2.15.0.2-36
  Version table:
 *** 2.15.0.2-36 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu     focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.15.0.2-36 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu jammy/arc amd64 Packages
     2.14.0.2-29 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.14.0.2-23 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.14.0-1 500
        500 http://mt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
     2.13.0+i643~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.13.0+i638~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.12.0+i620~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.12.0+i611~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.11.0+i593~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.11.0+i592~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.11.0+i571~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.11.0+i557~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.11.0+i547~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.11.0+i538~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.10.0+i526~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.10.0+i520~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.10.0+i509~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.10.0+i494~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.10.0+i482~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.10.0+i464~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.10.0+i455~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.10.0+i449~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.9.1+i435~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.9.1+i423~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.9.1+i419~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.9.1+i414~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.9.1+i405~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.9.0.0+i391~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.8.0.0+i374~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.8.0.0+i371~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.8.0.0+i362~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.8.0.0+i10~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.8.0.0+i5~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
libva2:
  Installed: 2.15.0.2-36
  Candidate: 2.15.0.2-36
  Version table:
 *** 2.15.0.2-36 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.15.0.2-36 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu jammy/arc amd64 Packages
     2.14.0.2-29 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.14.0.2-23 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.14.0-1 500
        500 http://mt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
     2.13.0+i643~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.13.0+i638~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.12.0+i620~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.12.0+i611~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.11.0+i593~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.11.0+i592~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.11.0+i571~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.11.0+i557~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.11.0+i547~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.11.0+i538~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.10.0+i526~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.10.0+i520~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.10.0+i509~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.10.0+i494~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.10.0+i482~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.10.0+i464~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.10.0+i455~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.10.0+i449~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.9.1+i435~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.9.1+i423~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.9.1+i419~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.9.1+i414~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.9.1+i405~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.9.0.0+i391~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.8.0.0+i374~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.8.0.0+i371~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.8.0.0+i362~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.8.0.0+i10~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     2.8.0.0+i5~u20.04 500
        500 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

---

The issue is related to steam

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 aptitude : Depends: aptitude-common (= 0.8.13-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libcwidget4 (>= 0.5.18-1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxapian30 (>= 1.4.17~) but it is not going to be installed
 i965-va-driver:i386 : Depends: libva-driver-abi-1.10:i386
 libva-glx2:i386 : Depends: libva-x11-2:i386 (>= 1.0.3) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libva2:i386 (>= 2.15.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libva2:i386 (< 2.15.0.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

---

*Result of Answer 1 (@nobody)*

I followed the list you mentioned. Still experiencing the issue.

cat /etc/apt/sources.list :

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20220809.1)]/ jammy main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy partner
```

sudo apt update :

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                                                         
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                    
Hit:4 https://apt.enpass.io stable InRelease                                                                                                                            
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                                   
Hit:6 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                     
Hit:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease                          
Hit:8 https://ocean.surfshark.com/debian stretch InRelease          
Hit:9 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:10 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu jammy  InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up-to-date.
W: https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

ls /etc/apt/ :
apt.conf.d  auth.conf.d  keyrings  preferences.d  sources.list  sources.list.d  sources.list.save  trusted.gpg  trusted.gpg.d

sudo apt -s full-upgrade :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
  i965-va-driver:i386 : Depends: libva-driver-abi-1.10:i386
 libva-glx2:i386 : Depends: libva-x11-2:i386 (>= 1.0.3) but it is not installed
                   Depends: libva2:i386 (>= 2.15.0.2) but it is not installed
                   Depends: libva2:i386 (< 2.15.0.2.1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

sudo apt --fix-broken install :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libgl1-amber-dri
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libva-x11-2:i386 libva2:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libva-x11-2:i386 libva2:i386
0 to upgrade, 2 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/99.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 311 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 173053 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libva2_2.15.0.2-36_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libva2:i386 (2.15.0.2-36) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libva2_2.15.0.2-36_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libva2/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from 
other instances of package libva2:i386
Preparing to unpack .../libva-x11-2_2.15.0.2-36_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libva-x11-2:i386 (2.15.0.2-36) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libva2_2.15.0.2-36_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry @guiverc you're right.

I updated the main thread:  Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: `apt-cache policy libva-x11-2:i386 libva2:i386 libva-x11-2 libva2`  please.

Comment: @nobody Added to main thread - thanks

Comment: Wellcome to ppa dependencies hell. :D  `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`  Search for focal sources and remove them. https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa

Comment: @nobody  I followed the link but most apt commands fail because of Dependency issue.  Would there be a way to uninstall steam and reset the package counter.  In Windows one could delete the update catalogue.

Comment: Any apt command fails with "The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 i965-va-driver:i386 : Depends: ..." The source of the problem is steam (https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/5339).

Is there a way I could eradicate steam and reinitialse the installer?

Comment: Your output shows two classic "trying to overwrite" errors, which usually occur when previous failed attempts to install have not been cleaned up.

Comment: And foreign repo's are still present too.

Comment: The system is highly unstable.  I set this computer up a couple of days ago. As this is a daily driver I would prefer to reinstall.  Today the system reported that it crashed on power up because of issues related to libva-x11-2.

My HP laptop is stable I daily desktop is Windows and I really came to like Ubuntu so I am having a second go (without Steam)

Answer (score 0):

First aid

```
sudo mv /usr/share/doc/libva-x11-2/changelog.Debian.gz /usr/share/doc/libva-x11-2/changelog.Debian.gz.bak
```

make a backup from your important data; And create a working install media (really just in case). This way it could work or not (dangerous)

First please restore default repository. Replace your
/etc/apt/sources.list with following content.

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy partner
```

move any file under

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

In a folder in your $HOME

Create file

```
/etc/apt/preferences.d/jammy.pref
```

with following content.

```
Package: *                                                                                                                                                   
Pin: release n=jammy 
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

This will force apt to install or downgrade packages from default repo.
Other files under

```
/etc/apt/preferences.d/
```

Move then also in your $HOME.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt -s full-upgrade
```

The second part of this is only a simulation.

This is a deep cut in your package-management. Study the output of the simulation well; before you try it with

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Comment: In my main post I added a section related to this answer.  I also included output of the various files that were modified and the repositories that are referenced by apt update